# how to fix this architecture error in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, architecture

I am getting this error report.  How to fix it?

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalPayment", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in PBMainViewController.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalPaymentViewController", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PBPayPalViewController in PBPayPalViewController.o   "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_PayPalPaymentViewController", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PBPayPalViewController in PBPayPalViewController.o   "_PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork", referenced
>   from:
>         -[PBMainViewController payWithPayPal:] in
>
> PBMainViewController
>
> .o
>       ld:
>
> symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: do you use any external library? probably they were not built for x86_64

Comment: how to fix in simulator

Comment: @angelina - i am using external library.how to fix it

Comment: Those external libraries should also be built for x86_64 environment

Comment: Hi check in all the classes your importing statements   # import "PBPayPalViewController.h" file or by mistaken your  #import "PBPayPalViewController.m". if exist change to #import "PBPayPalViewController.h" pls reply still find any issue

Answer (score 0):

At first, add a bridging header for paypal. see this [[How to call Objective-C code from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift) ]

Then include header into the header file for paypal. For example, In my case I use #import "PayPalMobile.h".

Link the frameworks for that library in the Linker section of "Build Phase" Settings.

Finally,
Clean and re-build the project.
[image]